# SSH or MobaXterm to AWS EC2 instance with saved password does not work

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, authentication, passwords, mobaxterm

I want to login (SSH) to AWS EC2 instance without typing username/password.  I used two ways to do that but did not helped and giving `access denied` error and ask to type password at prompt.

**First**

I used MobaXterm and in password management, I stored my username and password.

**Second**

I used putty explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/44106/is-there-a-way-to-auto-login-in-putty-with-a-password)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach first works for me.

**Why it did not worked earlier for me:**
Actually we have separate account for accessing AWS boxes via SSH (MobaXTerm), in that user/pwd combination there were certain characters which were causing problem.  Importantly `$` sign.  I changed my password and it worked for me.

Now with saved user/pwd combination it directly takes me to prompt.